# Flyway - Migrate to specific version

Tags: database, flyway

Is there a way to tell flyway to migrate only to specific version? For e.g. I have 4 versions e.g. `V1`, `V2`, `V3`and `V4` scripts and I want to migrate only to `V3` but not to v4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The migrate Task has a "target" attribute which lets you specify that.

> target - The target version up to which Flyway should consider
> migrations. Migrations with a higher version number will be ignored.
> The special value current designates the current version of the
> schema.

Doc for CommandLine: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/migrate

Example for maven

```
mvn -Dflyway.target=5.1 flyway:migrate
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add usage examples to your answer.

Comment: mvn -Dflyway.target=5.1 flyway:migrate

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, new one: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/migrate

Answer (score 8):

In case you use flyway command line and you want to migrate only to V3 you should do something like this:

```
flyway -configFiles=myconf.conf -target=3 migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to test you migrations, you can use Java API:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
    fluentConfiguration.target("3") // stable version
            .load()
            .migrate();
    // ... your SQL injection queries 
    fluentConfiguration
            .target("latest") // remaining versions you need to test
            .load()
            .migrate();
    // ... your SQL select checks
}
```